# How to move an object back and forth in p5js javascript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

After a few hours of work and research (I just started learning p5js and javascript) I have about 50 lines of code that creates a grid of circles and begins to move them across the canvas. Before I get into my issue, I will share the code.

```
var circles = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  for (var a = 50; a < width - 300; a += 20) {
    for (var b = 50; b < height - 300; b += 20) {
      circles.push(new Circle(a, b));
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(50);
  for (var b = 0; b < circles.length; b++) {
    circles[b].show();
  }
}

function Circle(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

  this.show = function() {
    fill(255);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
    if (this.x < 51) {
      this.x += 1
      this.y += 1
    } 
    if (this.x < 430) {
      this.x += 1
      this.y += 1
    }
    if (this.x > 430) {
      this.x -= 1
      this.y -= 1
    }
    if (this.x < 51) {
      this.x += 1
      this.y += 1
    } 
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is move this grid of circles starting at `(50,50)` to the bottom right corner. Once it hits `(width-50,height-50)` I'd like the movement to reverse back to the starting point, and then back the other way. This code moves the circles to the bottom right corner successfully, them something goes wrong. The circles don't reverse their movement, rather, they get messed up. I thought the if statements would handle this but I must be missing something. I trouble shooted for about an hour and now I thought I'd ask SO. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a moving direction to the object. Change the direction when the object goes out of bounds:

```js
var circles = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    for (var a = 50; a < width - 300; a += 20) {
        for (var b = 50; b < height - 300; b += 20) {
            circles.push(new Circle(a, b));
        }
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(50);
    for (var b = 0; b < circles.length; b++) {
        circles[b].show();
    }
}
    
function Circle(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = 1;
    this.dy = 1

    this.show = function() {
        fill(255);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);

        this.x += this.dx
        this.y += this.dy

        if (this.x < 51 || this.y < 51) {
            this.dx = 1
            this.dy = 1
        } 
        if (this.x > 430 || this.y > 430) {
            this.dx = -1
            this.dy = -1
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If you do not want to move the objects individually, you must use 1 direction of movement for all objects:

```js
var circles = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    for (var a = 50; a < width - 300; a += 20) {
        for (var b = 50; b < height - 300; b += 20) {
            circles.push(new Circle(a, b));
        }
    }
}

var dx = 1
var dy = 1
function draw() {
    background(50);
    mx = dx
    my = dy
    for (var b = 0; b < circles.length; b++) {
        circles[b].show(mx, my);
    }
}
    
function Circle(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.show = function(mx, my) {
        fill(255);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);

        this.x += mx
        this.y += my

        if (this.x < 51) {
            dx = 1
            dy = 1
        } 
        if (this.x > 430) {
            dx = -1
            dy = -1
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```